# How to perform a regression analysis on repeated measure data

Tags: regression, repeated-measures, mixed-model

I have two sets of data:

- A set of 100 observational variables for 10 subjects measured at three different time points
- Two performance variables for the same 10 subjects measured at the same three time points

I need to determine:

1. Whether the observational variables significantly differ across the three time points.
2. Whether the observational variables significantly correlate with the performance variables across the three time points. For example:

   - Does Variable X influence performance at time point 1
   - Does the change in variable X from point 1 to 2 influence a change in performance.

The goal is to provide variables that can be used to predict performance in a real world setting.

**What I've Done So Far**

For **1.** I've run a repeated measures ANOVA. For certain variables, sphericity was violated, and I used the Greenhouse-Geisser correction, but still had an Epsilon value under 0.7. I then ran Tukeys for all significant variables. I'm concerned about the post-hoc tests because I don't believe they are measuring within subject variables the same way that the repeated measures ANOVA did. I'm wondering if a linear-mixed-model approach is better, but am unsure how to proceed.

For **2.** I have considered doing a univariate regression analysis for each variable, but I do not know how to work with the repeated measures data to do this. I may have to use time as a covariate, but I am also unsure about this.

All in all, I am not well versed in statistics (and am new to this site). I am not sure if I am running the right tests, and am at a loss at how to proceed. I'd prefer to use SPSS and GraphPad Prism, but have some knowledge in R as well.